# Why does my wave signal from AD9850 / AD9851 DDS get cut off?

Tags: signal, dds, sine

I have the AD9850 and AD9851 version of [this](http://www.elecfreaks.com/store/dds-module-ad9850-p-260.html) board.

I have written the necessary code to interface these with my [microcontroller](http://www.micro4you.com/store/hy-mini-stm32v.html).

However, when I sample the sine output signal from the DDS it gets cut off like this:

[image: Sampled sine wave signal from DDS]

I have connected the wires like this:

GND <-> uC GND

D7 <-> uC GPIO

WCLK <-> uC GPIO

FQUP <-> uC GPIO

REST <-> uC GPIO

Vcc <-> 3.3V (Tried 5V as well)

V-ADJ <-> uC GND, Not Connected and different values between 0V and 3.3V has been tried.

I have been trying with and without jumper J3 and J2. Trying to change the potmeter etc. But there is no change except for when I use a DAC and send a few hundred millivolts signal in on V-ADJ, then the signal gets attenuated and eventually zero. I have not been able to increase the signal amplitude or change its offset so the signal don't get chopped.

The sine signal is directly connected to the microcontroller ADC pin.

I am running out of ideas and are therefore asking for help/tips/experiences.

I should have had an oscilloscope for debugging this signal, but none available at the moment.

The schematic is: [image]

Comment: I wonder if it's worth as a first step making sure your ADC capture / display code doesn't have some problem with underflow / signed numbers etc. Maybe just try 100mV or so DC on the ADC pin and see what output you get.

Comment: It's not clear to me where your ADC is connected to the circuit you posted.

Comment: @Andyaka: ADC is connected to the WAVE1 on header J7.

Comment: @PeterJ: I did connect the DAC to the ADC and it has no problems with range.

Comment: Have you got L1, L2 and L3 fitted? Also what frequency were you outputting (top picture)? What is your ADC circuit - presumably it is one that converts from 0V up to (say) 3.3V? Which pin is the ADC in your list (uC GPIO?)? Do you have any pull-up or pull-down resistors on that pin? I'm assuming 0V on the ADC "system" connects to gnd on J7.

Comment: @Andyaka: Not sure what the L1/L2/L3 question is about. 1 kHz in the top picture but same goes for 1 Hz to 250 kHz. ADC range is 0 - 3V3. No pull-up or pull-down on ADC pin (not internal or external). They have same ground. ADC pin was not in list, but have confirmed ADC functionality with DAC.

Comment: L1, L2 and L3 are (or appear to be) in series with the output chain from pin 21 to J7 - I'm assuming this is the output you are measuring. If not, you need to be specific about which pin on the chip you measured the signal.

Comment: @Andyaka: Yes this is the pin I am measuring. It's an 8th order ecliptic low-pass filter I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though this is not a good answer as I can't explain why, it solved my problem. What I did was applying 3V3 on the AD9850 comparators positive input pin.

This makes no sense to me, but the signal was then "lifted" and perfectly goes above 0V (by a few mV) on the sine negative peak.

Answer (score 0):

Several things:

- Make sure that your ADC minus(-) signal is GND. If it is by default something else you may see clipped signals like the one you are observing.
- your ADC might not be able rail to rail input. It means that value lower than the minumum input voltage of the ADC would get clipped
- There is a software bug somewhere.

Could you test with a DIY oscilloscope? (such as the one that uses your audio card of the PC. (if the frequency range falls in the audio range)

Comment: Rail-to-Rail no problem, tested with DAC directly connected to ADC and whole range can be used. ADC (-) is GND. No software bug found. What did solve it however was applying 3V3 on the AD9850 comparators positive input pin. This makes no sense to me, but the signal was then "lifted".